# Стохастические и вероятностные алгоритмы

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа

В чем разница между ***стохастическим*** и ***вероятностным*** алгоритмом?
Почему их определения разделены?
Являются ли они синонимами?

Comment: А какими именно определениями вы руководствуетесь?

Comment: Я руководствуюсь определениями /NIST/ Национального Института Стандартов и Технологий США. 1) Randomized algorithm - any algorithm that makes random (or pseudorandom) choices. 2) Probabilistic algorithm - any algorithm that works for all practical purposes but has a theoretical chance of being wrong.

Comment: И какое из них про "stochastic"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от конкретных определений.

Традиционно, понятие *вероятностного* алгоритма привязано к гарантиям на качество результата или время работы алгоритма. Вероятностные алгоритмы делятся на два подкласса:

1. либо гарантируют свое время работы, но дают точный результат лишь с некоей вероятностью,
2. либо гарантируют точность результата, но укладываются в заданное время работы лишь с некоей вероятностью.

*Стохастическим* же можно назвать вообще любой алгоритм, поведение которого зависит от случайных факторов, независимо от того, дает ли он какие-то гарантии на время работы/качество результата или нет.

Comment: Выходит, что вероятностный алгоритм является частным случаем стохастического? То есть стохастический алгоритм это более широкое понятие?

Comment: @Michael: Да, действительно, в рамках таких определений, вероятностный алгоритм является частным случаем стохастического.

Comment: Thanks a million. Русскоязычная википедия, в этом плане не настолько точна. Там эти понятия пытаются смешивать.